# Pantalla de carga entre páginas web en ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-3

Hola  como hace una cuando esta cargando la pagina ejemplo

Mi proyecto tiene la gem simple form

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Podrías mostrar la imagen de carga en la página y agregar un script al final que cambie el contenido (o esconda la imagen) al terminar de cargar la página. ¿Cuál es exactamente el uso que buscas?

Comment: @Gerry es que yo No se como se hace si podrias  enseñarme seria bueno ,gracias.